# Integral greater than $0$ implies the function greater than $0$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Is the following statement holds:

If $f$ is continuous in $[0,\infty)$. Suppose that 
$$\int_0^xf(t)\mathrm d t\geq 0$$
for all $x\geq 0$. Then $f(x)\geq 0$ for each $x\geq 0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**[image: Hint]${{{{{{{{{{{{{{{}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $\int_0^x \sin t\operatorname d t = 1-\cos x \geq 0$